# Better way to write this (jQuery)

Tags: javascript, jquery

I a newbie at this so excuse the lack of brevity. I am wondering if there is a better way to write this without repeating myself so much;

```js
var slider = $('input.slider'),
  percent = Math.ceil((($(slider).val() - $(slider).attr('min') - 20) / ($(slider).attr('max') - $(slider).attr('min'))) * 100),
  sliderCSS = {
    'background': '-webkit-linear-gradient(left, #6f00e4 0%, #0fe0ba ' + percent + '%, rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.1) ' + percent + '%)'
  };

$(slider).each(function() {
  $(this).css(sliderCSS);
}).on("input", function() {
  $(this).css(newSliderCSS);
});
```

I have try to store the repetitions in variables then try to call them as below but this does not work as expected.

```js
var slider = $('input.slider'),
  percent = Math.ceil((($(slider).val() - $(slider).attr('min') - 20) / ($(slider).attr('max') - $(slider).attr('min'))) * 100),
  sliderCSS = {
    'background': '-webkit-linear-gradient(left, #6f00e4 0%, #0fe0ba ' + percent + '%, rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.1) ' + percent + '%)'
  };

$(slider).each(function() {
  $(this).css(sliderCSS);
}).on("input", function() {
  $(this).css(newSliderCSS);
});
```

Where am I botching this? Thanks.

Comment: You should ask this on https://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would suggest reading up on lexical scope. You can read more about scope [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Closures).

This should clean it up a bit.

EDIT: I missed the reference to "this" in your example when I first looked. Here is an updated answer.

```
var slider = $('input.slider');

function calculatePercent(value, min, max) {
    return Math.ceil(((value - min - 20) / (max - min)) * 100);
}

function buildCss(value, min, max) {
    var percent = calculatePercent(value, min, max);
    return '-webkit-linear-gradient(left, #6f00e4 0%, #0fe0ba ' + percent + '%, rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.1) ' + percent + '%)';
}

$(slider).each(function() {
    $(this).css('background', buildCss(this.value, this.min, this.max));
    $('#mainSendAmount').text(this.value);
}).on("input", function() {
    $(this).css('background', buildCss(this.value, this.min, this.max));
});
```

Comment: `slider = $(...)` and then later `$(slider)`... why??

Answer (score 0):

Here's how I would simplify:

```
var slider = $('input.slider');

$(slider).each(function() {
  var percent = Math.ceil(((this.value - this.min - 20) / (this.max - this.min)) * 100);

  $(this).css('background', makeGradient(percent));
  $('#mainSendAmount').text(this.value);

  $(this).on('input', function() {
    $(this).css('background', makeGradient(percent));
  });
});

var makeGradient = function(percent) {
  return '-webkit-linear-gradient(left, #6f00e4 0%, #0fe0ba ' + percent + '%, rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.1) ' + percent + '%)';
};
```

Comment: This fails for some reason. I think it is because you called the `makeGradient` var before defining it but I could be wrong.

Comment: Yes.  Just change that from `var makeGradient = function(percent) {` to `function makeGradient(percent){`

Comment: Yes, I forgot non declaration functions are not hoisted.